# (segmentation fault) core dump in quicksort code in c

Tags: c

I have made code for Quicksort .It works well in some cases but in most of the cases it causes core dump problem.mostly cases are long input >10 , already big sorted array. why it is happening ?

This is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void quicksort(int arr[],int s,int l)
{
    int temp;

    if(l-s <= 1) return ;

    int i=s+1,j=s+1;

    for(i;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]<=arr[s])
        {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            j++;
        }
    }

    temp = arr[j-1];
    arr[j-1] = arr[s];
    arr[s] = temp;  
    quicksort(arr,s,j);
    quicksort(arr,j,l);
}
int main()
{
    int arr[50],n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

    quicksort(arr,0,n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("\n%d\n",arr[i]);

}
```

Comment: Show us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you used a debugger to try and find the problem yourself? At the very least it will tell you the line of code causing the segv. Or even with printf debugging statements. If you have already done that then please provide the findings.

Comment: And you're running that with `n` being 50 at most?

Comment: Apart from the missing check that `n` isn't more than 50 your code looks good to me. But better use meaningful variable names!

Comment: Show a minimal sample data set that causes the crash...

Comment: Found one myself: http://ideone.com/Dq5QgN (it's the 28 being twice in the input array)

Comment: One 7-entry data set that crashed (for me, on Mac OS X 10.10.5 with GCC 5.1.0) was: `61
88
36
61
4
86
2`.

Answer (score 4):

Correct the line (remove '=')

```
if(arr[i]<=arr[s])
```

to

```
if(arr[i]<arr[s])
```

It is going into an inifinite loop and hence causing a stack over flow.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on why it's going into an infinite loop?

Comment: This change certainly made the code work for me, on the previously crashing set of 7 numbers, and on other previously crashing sets of up to 20 random elements.

Comment: core was generated when you have any number repeated.  This issue can happen with two number as well. first input 2 and then give 1 and 1, You can see core is getting generated after some time.

Comment: 2 input and both are one case,

first call quicksort(arr,0,n);
in this case s =0 and l = 2
When you call 
 quicksort(arr,s,j);
s = 0 and j = 2, So the function quicksort is called with same parameter, hence it repeats for ever....